# How to run mockgen during build?

Tags: unit-testing, go, gomock

I have started using [gomock](https://code.google.com/p/gomock/) to create mock objects for unit testing. Gomock requires that that I run the `mockgen` command with certain argument in order to generate code for the mock. This needs to be done again every time the interfaces that is being mocked changes. I therefore thought it might make sense to have `go build` run `mockgen` with the appropriate arguments.

Is there a way to have `go build` to run a script or shell command before building a package?

If not, how do you generate your mocks and keep them up to date?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there exist any hooks into `go build` that would make this possible.

One solution would be to use make. Your `Makefile` might resemble this:

```
.PHONY: build test

build:
    go build

test:
    mockgen ...
    go test
```